# Modify javascript to get TWO query strings

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have this javascript code that sends the value of what is entered in the an input bar to a php file that fetches rows from a database according to the value of what is entered into the input field. I need to edit this code so that the javascript not only sends the value of what is being entered into the input bar to the php, but also another javascript variable.

The code is as follows:

```
function showFriends(str)
{
    var cake = document.getElementById("cake");

    if(str.length == 0)
    { 
        document.getElementById("livesearch1").
        innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("livesearch1").
        style.border="0px";
        return
    }

    xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject()


    var url="petition_send.php"
    url=url+"?q="+str
    url=url+"&sid="+Math.random()
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged 
    xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true)
    xmlHttp.send(null)
} 

function stateChanged() 
{ 
    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete")
    { 
        document.getElementById("livesearch1").
        innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
        document.getElementById("livesearch1").
        style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
    } 
}

function GetXmlHttpObject()
{
    var xmlHttp=null;
    try
    {
    //Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
        xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (e)
    {
    //Internet Explorer
    try
    {
        xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    }
        return xmlHttp;
    }
```

I need the var url to be equivalent to "petition_send.php?petition_ID=cake&"

but, for some reason, the code doesn't work when I write it like that.

Any thoughts?

Comment: write it like what? Provide an example.

Comment: it would be much easier to write if you used an ajax library like jquery yui mootools etc... are they an option?

Comment: WHERE ARE YOUR SEMICOLONS?!?!?! (semicolon insertion #ftf)

Comment: @Jacob Relkin, AFAIK there is exactly one place where JavaScript's semicolon auto-insertion is useful: code-golf.

Answer (score 0):

if jquery is an option you can use something like

```
$("#mybutton").click(function(){
   $("#livesearch1").load("petition_send.php", 
      { "q" : $("#cake").text(),
        "sid" : Math.random() }).css("border","0px");
});
```

which is a lot simpler

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
$('#livesearch1').load('petition_send.php', 
  { q: $('#cake').value(), sid: Math.random() },
  function() { $('#livesearch1').addClass('with-border'); }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to add another parameter (petition_ID) to the current query string and set the value of petition_ID to the value of var cake?

```
function showFriends(str)
{
    var cake = document.getElementById("cake");

    if(str.length == 0)
    { 
        document.getElementById("livesearch1").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("livesearch1").style.border="0px";
        return;
    }

    xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();


    var url="petition_send.php";
    url=url+"?q="+str;
    // additional param
    url=url+"&petition_ID="+cake;
    url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
    xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```